# Question 3.7 from Brezis' book of Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

**Question:** Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $A\subset E$ be a subset that is closed in the weak topology $\sigma(E, E')$. Let $B\subset E$ be a subset that is compact in the weak topology $\sigma(E, E')$. Prove that $A+B$ is closed in $\sigma(E, E')$.

**Brezis' solution is:**
For every $y\in B$ $\underbrace{\text{there exists a convex neighborhood}\; V(y)\; of\; 0\; \text{such that}\;(x+W)\cap(A+B)=\varnothing}_{(1)}$

(since $A+y$ is closed and $x\notin A+y$).

$\underbrace{\text{Clearly}}_{(2)}$

$$B\subset\displaystyle\bigcup_{y\in B}\left(y-\frac{1}{2} V(y)\right),$$
and since $B$ is compact, there is some finite set $I$ such that
$$B\subset\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}\left(y_i-\frac{1}{2} V(y_i)\right)\; \text{with}\; y_i\in B.$$
Set
$$W=\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I} V(y_i).$$
We claim that $(x+W)\cap (A+B)=\varnothing$. Indeed, suppose by contradiction that there exists some $\omega \in W$ such that $x+\omega \in (A+B)$. Hence there is some $i\in I$ such that $$x+\omega \in A+y_i-\frac{1}{2} V(y_i).$$
Since $V(y_i)$ is convex it follows that there exists some $\omega'\in V(y_i)$ such that $\underbrace{x+\omega'\in A+y_i}_{(3)}$. Consequently $(x+V(y_i))\cap (A+y_i)\neq \varnothing;$ absurd.

**Doubt:**
Would you give me a hint to solve it in another way? (Different from the solution in Brezis' Book?) **OR** Explain the solution in Brezi's Book more step by step? (Explaining why every conclusion?)

In case, of choose for explaining Brezis' solution, I would like to understand the following:

1. Which results assure me that really exists a convex neighborhood of zero for every $y \in B$?
2. For me was not clear that
   $$B\subset\displaystyle\bigcup_{y\in B}\left(y-\frac{1}{2} V(y)\right)$$
   and also that this is an open cover of opens set? (is this interpretation right, isn't?)
3. Why $x+\omega'\in A+y_i$ and not $x+\omega'\in A+y_i-\frac{1}{2}V(y_i)$, since $\omega'\in V(y_i)$?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one guess is that you don't mention what Brezis's method is. Not everyone has access to the book.

Comment: Can you do it if $\sigma(E,E')$ is replaced by the norm topology?  That would be my first "sanity check."

Comment: @Jose27 I'll post Brezis' method! Thanks.

Comment: @PeterMorfe Maybe, however, I'll post Brezis' solution, in order to find, at least, a step-by-step proof in the same path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\sigma(E,E')$ topology is a topology that makes $E$ a topological vector space, so, also a topological group with addition. Now, the proof of the fact that $A+B$ is closed if $A$ compact, and $B$ closed works almost like in the case of $E= \mathbb{R}$.  It is easiest to work with (generalized) sequences. Let $a_n + b_n \to c$. Now, $a_n$ being from $A$, has a convergent subsequence $a_{n_k}\to a$.  So $a_{n_k}\to a$, $a_{n_k} + b_{n_k} \to c$ implies $b_{n_k} \to c-a$. Since $B$ is closed, we have $c-a= b\in B$. Therefore $c = a+ (c-a) \in A+B$.

Now, in general, usual sequences might not work, but all of the above works as well for generalized sequences. And they feel like the usual ones.

Comment: By generalized sequences, do you mean 'nets'? Where can I find the definition of 'topological group with addition?

Comment: @Silvinha: Nets, indeed.  The statement works even for non-abelian Hausdorff topological groups: $A$ compact, $B$ closed implies $AB$ closed.  In the case of abelian topological groups, the notation for the operation is sometime $+$. Like $E$ with addition.